# How to increase url page by one in javascript console (F12) after = sign?

Tags: javascript

How do I do that in javascript console? I found it here in stackoverflow a while ago by searching in google, but I can't seem to find it either in google or here this moment. Please correct me if my question is not clear since I dont remember how I found that post or refer me to a link.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will extract the digits after a equal-sign of a variable named 'variable' from the current URL and adds 1 to it.

URL: http://www.whatever.com/folder/another_folder/?variable=12&another_variable=13

`var newUrl = ++/.*:\/\/.*\/.*variable=(\d*)/.exec(document.location.href)[1]`

I will break it up for you:

- `++` : Adds 1 to the found value
- `/.*:\/\/.*\/.*variable=(\d*)/` : Regex that finds the numerical value after a variable called 'variable'
- `exec(document.location.href)[1]` : Executes the regex on the current URL and returns an array with data (the first group can be found in the ar)

Comment: will it work if i do this?                                                                                                         var ourLocation = document.URL;
console.log("Currently at " + ourLocation);
var newUrl = ++/.*:\/\/.*\/.*ourLocation =(\d*)/.exec(document.location.href)[1];

Comment: No the variable is the variable name in the URL you want to use for extraction: So if you have an URL like: http://whatever.com/?var1=324&var2=454&var3=12 you'd be able to fetch any of the variables value by changing the 'variable' to that name.